# Add php code each 12 items starting from 2nd item

Tags: php, loops, if-statement, each, modulus

I have some loop. How can i optimize this code that it would be executed each 12 items starting from 2nd item. I'm using hardcoded code for each of +12 item, but of course this is not a good solution :) I know it's easy to do and i was trying to do it with modulus operator, however it worked somehow incorrectly.

```
<?php if( ($counter == 2) || ($counter == 14) || ($counter == 26) || ($counter == 38) || ($counter == 50) || ($counter == 62) || ($counter == 74) || ($counter == 86) || ($counter == 98 .... ?>
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: It might be useful for you to include the modulus statement you attempted. That way, we can help to clear any misconceptions you might have of the use of the modulo operator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Answer**

Take a look at the [Modulus operator (`%`)](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php):

```
<?php
    if ( ( $counter - 2 ) % 12 == 0 ) {
        //....
    }
?>
```

---

**Explanation**

> The Modulus operator (`$a % $b`) is the remainder of `$a` divided by `$b`.

- `$counter - 2` - as you're starting with an offset of `2`, remove that from `$counter`
- `% 12` - will return the remainder of `$counter - 2` divided by `12`
- `== 0` - if the above returns `0`, you know that it is exactly divisible

Comment: And why not `if ($counter % 12 === 2) ...` ?

Comment: @naomik because the OP states that he wants to check "*each 12 items starting from 2nd item*"

Comment: @naomik I answered this way (deleted answer because this one is better) You will need also check if $counter == 2 also.

Comment: @naomik Also, I'm using `==` instead of `===` because the OP uses `==` - I don't know the value of `$counter`

Comment: @PVL Actually, `0 % 12` will return `0` so you don't need to check that! It will still work fine.

Comment: Working just great. Thanks for help and explanation ;)

Comment: @MIC My pleasure. Glad I could help :)